# How to find differences between 2 almost-identical files very fast?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures, comparison

If you have two mainly identical files with 1000s of records, how will you write code to find differences between them. Assume that unix/linux commands are not allowed to be used.

My idea:

Because most of entries are the same, we can sort the entries of the two files, then compare each entry one by one, e.g. entry i in file1 compare to entry i in file2. It is O(n lg n), n is size of file.

Are there O(n) solution ?

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like homework...

Comment: Up to a certain size of input, hash tables could give you linear time.

Comment: Does position of identical records need to match or could two identical records be found in different places between the two files?

Comment: Both are possible, we need to consider the 2 cases.

Comment: @GWW I don't think so, but then, I have never taken programming class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash tables are your friends.

1. Get a record from file 1.
2. Hash it.
3. Get the corresponding memory address.
4. Set it to `1`.
5. Repeat for all records in file 1.
6. Repeat for all records in file 2, but add 2 instead of setting to 1.

Now you know which record exists in both files (value 3), which exists in the first file only (value 1), and which exists in the second file only (value 2).  And in linear time.

**Note:** If you're implementing your own hash table, you have to handle growing the size of your table as needed, as well as collisions.  I'm sure if you could do that then you wouldn't have a hard time with this question, so use a library.

Comment: Unless you have a perfect hash, you're likely going to get values higher than 3. What do you plan to do in that case?

Comment: Collision detection must be implemented with the hash table, I was simplifying... although if someone asked me to implement it, I'd simply store a different hash of each object together with its counter (error-prone but so unlikely I wouldn't worry for homework).

Comment: You could always hash the hash. (It's faster.)

Comment: @muntoo hashing a hash does nothing for collision handling, :(

Comment: @muntoo, if you have duplicates in your hash generation algorithm, hashing the hashes is _not_ going to solve that. The hashed hashes will also be identical.

Comment: @paxdiablo: not necessarily. You could append the hash to the data and hash that again.

Comment: @ame, if you have two identical lines, they will have the same hash. If you then append that hash to the line, they're _still_ identical, as is the second-gen hash they would generate. No, if you want a different hash-of-hash value, you need to introduce something _different._

Comment: @paxdiablo: since we were talking collisions here, I would assume that you have two entries `E1` and `E2` and that `h(E1) == h(E2)`, it does not imply however that `E1 == E2` and therefore arne's solution makes sense.

Comment: @bdares Oh, whoops. :) Well, you could always make a hash of half the data as well as your 'full hash'. It is still faster, and isn't as error prone as my original suggestion. ;)